# Testing with SQLAchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
class Foo:
    def __init__(...):
        self.engine = sa.create_engine('...')
        self.conn = self.engine.connect()
```

Inside a class there is a method which manipulates data within a transaction:

```
def add_product(...):
    with self.conn.begin():
         self.conn.execute(self.product_table.insert(), ...)
```

I have tests in py.test so after each test I want to rollback all the changes that the code made within the test, so I created a yield fixture:

```
@yield_fixture(scope='function'):
def mocked_foo():
     foo = Foo(...)
     transaction = foo.conn.begin()
     yield foo
     transaction.rollback()
```

What I expected is that setting fixture's scope to `function` at the end of each the test method the `transaction.rollback()` should undo all the changes object `foo` made but this does not seem to be true. I see the product in the database which is added in a `add_product()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was totally my fault. I did not pay attention at the fact that the table was a MyISAM one. After changing engine to `InnoDB` everything went fine.